# Passing name of cell to another view via table cell button

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, button

Alright, so I want to pass the name contained in a cell of a table in one view controller to an array in another view controller. I want to do this via a button that is also contained in the cell of the first table.

Here is where the table cells are described:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// add "add" button
UIButton *addFriendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
addFriendButton.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);

[cell addSubview:addFriendButton];

[addFriendButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(addFriend:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;

}
```

And here is where the button method would be described:

```
- (IBAction)addFriend:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Add friend.");



}
```

The name of the first view controller - the one doing the pass - is called ViewController - and the second view controller - the one receiving the passed info - is called MyMealViewController. The array that I want the passed info to be stored in is called myMenuArray.

I think that's basically all the relevant information. If there is any additional information that you need from me - or if you need clarification on the question I'm asking - to make my question answerable, please let me know!

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. What's not working? One obvious bug is that in the case that the dequed cell is nil, you allocate the new cell after you have done the configuration of the cell. You should move the cell allocation up to immediately below the dequeue

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug, I changed it as you suggested. As for my question: it's not that anything is "not working" it's just that I need some guidance in figuring out how to implement the "addFriend" action in the second block of code that would pass the name once the button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[addFriendButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(addFriend:) toTarget:self      withObject:cell.textLabel.text]
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)addFriend:(NSString *)theFriendName 
{
   NSLog(@"Add friend.");
// Now here you make the instance of the new ViewController and you set the text you are     adding.
MyViewController *theVC = [MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController"     bundle:nil];
[theVC setNewFriend:theFriendName];
[self presentModalViewController:theVC animated:YES];

}
```